# Does Visual Studio Debugger use many resources when left on overnight?

Tags: website, visual-studio-2015, resources, debugger

I use Visual Studio to debug web programs (web sites run on a local server), and when I close the browser, I often forget to choose "Stop Debugging".

Does Visual Studio use many resources on the computer if left on **inadvertently over-night**?

*For example:*  CPU, memory, electricity to run the computer?

I am using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Depends. If it hits a breakpoint, it'll just stop. If it's tracking memory/CPU usage, then no more than it would do during the day. The extra electricity cost will be negligible, vs leaving the machine idle. Why not set up a scheduled task to hibernate the machine at a specific time, or set a power profile that kicks in which tunes down to an energy saving profile?

Comment: If you were using the performance profiler it could also fill up your C: drive with temporary data. Not a great thing to do to an SSD.

Comment: @spikey_richie -- if you wish, you may make answers based on your comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @romen --  -- if you wish, you may make answers based on your comment.  Thanks!